# Dynamic object creation in python

Tags: python

I am very new to python and learning about object and classes. Currently what I am trying to do is dynamically create objects based on a number given by the user.

for example:

```
class Color:
    __init__(self):
        self.rgb = ()

for thing in *range provided by user*:
    thing = Color()
    thing.rgb = *something assigned randomly*
```

i've tried this but it just recreates the object in the same space of memory so i only end up with one

Comment: Why not pass the random thing as an argument to `__init__`?

Comment: Why are you assigning a new instance of `Color` to your loop index?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you want *all* of the created objects to exist later, you'd need to append them to a list or other container.